# Redirecting users to a view based on their role

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have three user roles:
- admin
- instructor
- student

I need to redirect admin & instructor to an admin panel view and then redirect student to a different view. Can anyone recommend what is my best way to go about doing this? I am new to laravel and struggling to understand how i might make this work. Thanks.

My current web.php is;

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::redirect('/', '/login');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::middleware('can:manage_users')->group(function(){
        Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController'); //URL to access, followed by controller created
        Route::resource('/courses', 'CoursesController');
        Route::resource('/modules', 'ModulesController');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `authenticated()` function in login controller

```
   protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {

       if ($user->hasRole('admin') ) {
                $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
            }elseif($user->hasRole('instructor'))
            {
                $this->redirectTo = route('instructor.dashboard');
            }elseif($user->hasRole('student'))
            {
                $this->redirectTo = route('student.dashboard');
            }

    }
```

And you can edit `Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`  like this.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ( \Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }elseif(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->hasRole('instructor')) {
            return redirect()->route('instructor.dashboard');
        }elseif(\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->hasRole('student')) {
            return redirect()->route('student.dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

You can define `admin.dashboard, instructor.dashboard, student.dashboard` routes in web.php

Comment: Thanks for this, can you advise if there is a specific way i should define this in the web.php? I am new to laravel i really appreciate your help.